# would a wifi repeater get this signal through a wall?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I live in a high rise apartment so the reinforced concrete walls pretty much block most signals.

[image]

I am not allowed to drill holes to run an ethernet cable

I can't replace or move the router either its a ONT given by the ISP

I am thinking of buying something like a TP-Link AC1750 and placing it at X

Comment: Did you try positioning the router-WAP unit so that the WiFi signal would pass through the door instead of the wall?  IOW not at your proposed X location, but rather to the right of the existing(?) router location.

Comment: It might... but only a real test will give you the answer :). Have you considered a powerline carrier?